# PHP MySQL Populated Select Options making the right one "Selected"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently outputting a select menu using the following code;

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
}
```

I'm wondering how I can make the one that is selected in the database appear as selected, seeings as the options are dynamically drawn and added?

Edit: I still want the other options that aren't selected to appear in the list so it can be changed.

Comment: There's an attribute `selected`. Compare something with something and set it: `<option value="" selected>Name</option>`

Comment: Write solutions as answers not parts of questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You try this way:**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
     $selected=$row['id']==$current_id? "selected": "";  //$current_id is which you want to selected..
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'" '. $selected.' >'.$row['title'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: I got this working by joining the two corresponding tables, where id = mediaid, and having $current_id=$row['mediaid'] - but it's only displaying the selected option now, I still want the others to appear to so they can be selected. Any ideas?

Comment: can use `multiple` attribute in select tag like `<select name="any_name"  multiple >`

Comment: My apologies, I'll clarify further. It's only displaying the <option> that is selected now. I still want the other <options> that aren't selected to appear as well, so that the option can be changed.

Comment: i can't understand your lang. please give me output html code in manualy.

Comment: Sorry - the problem isn't the code you gave me, It's in my query. I'll mark your answer as correct shortly.

Comment: If you see multiple selected option then use `multiple` attribute. Or if you see single selected option then previous code is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Make an if condition and then use `selected` Attribute

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
         if (your condition) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'" selected>'.$row['title'].'</option>';
    } else {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
    }
    }
```

Comment: add a space before 'selected'.